# is it possible to change first value of KEY_ID in sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

in database i use this code 
        KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
that cause the KEY_ID start from 1 to ...

but i want to start from 0 instead of 1
is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html#the_autoincrement_keyword) says:

> The ROWID chosen for the new row is at least one larger than the largest ROWID that has ever before existed in that same table. If the table has never before contained any data, then a ROWID of 1 is used.

So it is not possible to start from zero, except by manually inserting the value `0` for the first row.